# Angular Micro Front End with Module Federation throws CORS error when deployed

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I have a host and two micro front ends (All are angular 14). This works fine in local development. Finally I containerized them and ran in docker. My host container trying to get the `remoteEntry.js` from the two micro front end containers, while doing so CORS error arises.

Please advice how to overcome this.

Access to script at 'http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**My webpack.config.js of one of the two mfe**

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.json'),
  [
    /* mapped paths to share */
    '@shared'
  ]);

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: 'all',
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    }
  },
  output: {
    uniqueName: "medicalcoding",
    publicPath: "auto"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      library: { type: "module" },

      // For remotes (please adjust)
      name: "medicalcoding",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        './Module': './projects/medicalcoding/src/app/app.module.ts',
      },

      // For hosts (please adjust)
      // remotes: {
      //     "mainapp": "http://localhost:5000/remoteEntry.js",
      //     "paymentposting": "http://localhost:4200/remoteEntry.js",

      // },

      shared: share({
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
      })

    })
    , sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

**My webpack.config.js of host**

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.json'),
  [
    /* mapped paths to share */
    '@shared'
  ]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "mainapp",
    publicPath: "auto",
    scriptType: 'text/javascript'
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      library: { type: "module" },

      // For remotes (please adjust)
      // name: "mainapp",
      // filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      // exposes: {
      //     './Component': './projects/mainapp/src/app/app.component.ts',
      // },        

      // For hosts (please adjust)
      remotes: {
        "medicalcoding": "http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js",
        "paymentposting": "http://localhost:4000/remoteEntry.js"
      },

      shared: share({
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
      })
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, different ports are different domains. So, even if these microfrontends are coming from localhost, their ports are different and have to be whitelisted in your server. You didn't provide information about the server part so it's difficult to say where and what exactly you should change since every implementation is different.

Basically, you have to whitelist your calling domain in the server. For a explanation on how cors works, take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Since you wrote this is an angular application, I guess you are using Webpack to serve these apps. In your `devServer`, you can set CORS headers:

```
devServer: {
  ...,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
  }
},
```

Comment: Hi, My host app is running on http://localhost:5000, on-load this host app is trying to get the `remoteEntry.js`  from http://localhost:3000/ and http://localhost:4000/ (Two mfe). I understand I've to enable CORS in these two mfe but do not know, how to do it in webpack.config.js. Since these two mfes are angular apps, not API

Comment: Also I'm running the docker container in my local machine. I've not hosted it anywhere still.

Comment: I edited my answer adding an example for webpack. please note the webpack devServer is meant only for development environments.

Comment: If it is an API , I know how to add allow orgin headers. But these are angular apps

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting the same error again

Comment: Can you post your webpack config?

Comment: I've added them in my question now

Comment: That should be working. Which browser are you using? Note that chrome won't allow CORS on localhost. Have you tried with any other browser? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743

Comment: But we have a restriction that our clients should only use Chrome. But chrome throws CORS error. So I have added the custom http header `add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";` in my nginx config file. Now it is working

Comment: You didn't mention you were using nginx, there were multiple issues then. If this answer fixes the issue in other browsers it should be accepted, since it solves a generic problem not related to business constraints.

Comment: can anyone please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75958591/nx-mfe-angular-module-federation-not-able-to-access-remote-micro-front-end

Comment: is there any fix for this as I am getting CORS issue in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: @SyedAbdulHannan See my comment up, from March 3. 2023